# What approach should i take for creating global application for audit trailing of different systems?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee

I want to build a standalone global audit trail application which can trace all the audit(events) logs sent to it from different applications through webservice call or any other channel.

The issue i see here is i don't want to hamper the performance of the calling application to wait for the response as ideally not expecting any response back to calling app.

If i go with webservice approach then the caller application will wait for the response (both case synchronized /asynchronized call) are there any other best approach for this solution.

There will be n no of application which will be sending their audit logger to this application so need idea which i can scale up parallel if required.

Thanks for going through my request!!!

Comment: I would recommend to use kafka to send logs in async way. Each application will have its own topics and partitions basis the throughput. Set Kafka producer in async manner, and caller application will not have any latency implication. Now in your logging application, maybe you can have consumers and send this data to Hive or Elasticsearch for log querying. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, Kafka is one of good use case but is there any approach using J2EE/Spring as these tech stack are already in the eco-systems bringing any new stack will be little difficult for all the applications

Comment: Your logging platform can expose an API which will actually interact with kafka in async manner, thus each application doesn't need to know underlying infrastructure for logging. Since pushing data to kafka is async, mainly thread is a background thread which will push to kafka, your API will be lightweight, and latencies can be in 5-10ms. Instead of spring use async frameworks like vert.x or node.js.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way.  I would use an *existing* (off the shelf) system for gathering log events and analyzing them.  One place to start reading: https://opensource.com/article/18/9/open-source-log-aggregation-tools

Comment: As i need a audit systems so can't rely on logging system as sometime during crash scenarios logging files and cache are cleared first.

Answer (score 0):

We would be using **Kafka** for this approach.
Hopefully it is having good performance and scalable.